# how to make an api call when the form is submitted ? and show message based on the response

Tags: apex, visualforce

i want to send the form data to an url where i can access the form data and send sms using twilio. I know how to configure twilio and send sms using it.

apex class:

```
public class SMS {
    public Message__c message { get; set; }

    public sms() {
        message = new Message__c();
    }


    public PageReference save() {
        System.debug(System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('mobile'));
        insert message;
        return null;
    }

}
```

visual force page:

```
<apex:page controller="sms">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Sent SMS">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="List">
            <apex:form>    

                <apex:inputField value="{!Message.Mobile__c}" id="mobile" /><br />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Message.Text_Message__c}" id="sms_Text" /><br />               
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I want to access the form data in apex class and send it into an API call .. How to achieve it ?

Comment: What type of API, is it SOAP or REST?

Comment: @SarojBera Actually i am new to visual force. which would be better? i just need to send data and save it in database and return response.

Comment: Saroj is asking about the SMS API you're using. You don't usually get to choose which technology (SOAP/REST) you're using once you choose a provider.

Comment: @sfdcfox maybe my question is not clear enough. i just want to send the form data to an url where i can access the form data and send sms using twilio. I know how to configure twilio and send sms using it.

Answer (score 3):

For Twilio you don't have to call the API directly. Twilio provides a [Helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/salesforce) to send the SMS. The detailed documentation is available [here](http://twilio-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/messages.html).

In summary, you have to install their unmanaged package as mentioned [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/salesforce). And then using the helper classes you can [send the SMS](http://twilio-salesforce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/messages.html).

Please note you need the ACCOUNT_SID and AUTH_TOKEN as mentioned [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-how-to-change-them) from the Twilio account, and the SMS charges will be billed to this account.

```
String ACCOUNT_SID = 'AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
String AUTH_TOKEN = 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY';
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

List<TwilioNameValuePair> properties = new List<TwilioNameValuePair>();
properties.add(new TwilioNameValuePair('To','+13216851234'));
    properties.add(new TwilioNameValuePair('From','+15555555555'));
    properties.add(new TwilioNameValuePair('MediaUrl','https://www.twilio.com/packages/company/img/logos_downloadable_round.png'));

TwilioMessage message = client.getAccount().getMessages().create(properties);
```